# Save Images into Sql Server Database Table using asp.net 4.0 ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a form where users are able to upload images to the website. The images are stored in binary, in the table.

I use ajax and JQuery on the site and it is never reloaded so when a users enter the data and push submit, the page is not reloaded.  Instead I use ajax to upload the the data to the server.

When I just passthrough text it looks like this:

```
$("#storeDataAndImgBtn").bind("click", function () {
    var msg = $("#emailMsg").val();
    var from = $("#fromEmail").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/storeDataAndImg",
        data: "{\"from\":\"" + from + "\" ,\"msg\":\"" + msg + "\" ,\"value\":\" 'image should be here' \" }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (temp) {
            alert(temp.d);
            $("#mailForm").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#overlay").fadeOut();
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My question is how i can passthrough the image so that I can store it in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the image is just a `Input Type="File"`.  If this is the case, you cannot access the Input field using Ajax due to security reasons.  I believe the best solution is using an `IFrame` for the submit target.  It's not pretty but it works.

[SOF - How to make Asynchronous(AJAX) File Upload using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe)

Your other option is to use a Flash/Silverlight/etc plugin to.  I am currently using SWFUpload.

[SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/project)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would suggest not storing the image in the database. Instead, store images on the server's file-system.

Refer here for similar/related questions:
[store image in database or in a system file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766048/store-image-in-database-or-in-a-system-file)

Comment: Okay, so say that I actually change so that I store the images onto the server's file-system instead. How do I (without reloading the page, making a post) store the image onto the file-system?

Comment: Hmm, using Ajax this doesn't really happen out of the box; but you may find what you need here: http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/01/Create-An-Ajax-Style-File-Upload.aspx and also a similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254831/asp-net-free-ajax-file-upload-control