# How can I do File Upload using hidden iframe + jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

We all know it's not possible to do file upload using jquery alone. But it is possible to do a work around using jquery and hidden IFrame.

I have found four solutions using this method, but don't see how I can implenent them.

1. [This solution found here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe), is one way of doing it. But I'm not sure if it's the best way. (not tested)
2. [Using jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) is another option. I tried following [this example](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/jquery-form-plugin-and-php-file-uploads/), but it did not help. The solution loads my uploader.php in a new page and it's not able to get file info. I can't see it using IFrame.
3. [Ajax File Upload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) is another solution - this one is crating a dynamic IFrame. Looking at the example code, I can't fiure out how to implement this.
4. The last solution is [AJAX file  upload](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html) from Webtoolkit. Here I can't figure out where I should declare what PHP file it should load for file handling.

Does anyone have a working example using one of these methods?
I have used Uploadify in a another solution - but I don't want to use flash now.

Comment: First one is good enough. I do it so.

Comment: But where does it say what PHP file should handle the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #3 This is basically right off their website.

I'm a .Net guy, so I can't really help you on the .php handler you'll need to receive the file, but I hope you find this useful.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://www.phpletter.com/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.phpletter.com/contents/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxFileUpload()
    {
        $.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                //YOUR URL TO RECEIVE THE FILE
                url: 'http://localhost/testing/postfile.php',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',           
                success: function (data, status)
                {
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, e)
                {
                    alert(data.error);
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        )
        return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableForm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ajax File Upload</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input"></td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Please select a file and click Upload button</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now that I have the uploader.php output correct JSON, I discover that no POST data is being sent, and `$_FILES` is NULL. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Looks like you found your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675908/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-or-files-data. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I ended up making a solution using the plugin from # 3. The only problem is that the only data past from the FORM to my uploader.php file, is the `$_FILE` data. I also need to retrieve `$_POST` data, so I will try (again) to make a solution using # 2.