# AjaxFileUpload Plugin does not retrieve $_POST or $_FILES data

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

Ok, I hope this will be my last question in a series of Q's regarding dynamic file upload.

I'm using [AjaxFileUpload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) and try to work with the FORM data in my uploader.php. The problem is that both `$_POST` and `$_FILES` is NULL.

This is my HTML code:

```
  <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="current_path" value="<?php echo $fb->relative_url; ?>" />
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" class="button uploadImage" value="<?php _e('Upload File') ?>" /> <br />
  </form>
```

And this is my JS script:

```
  //File upload
    jQuery('.uploadImage').live('click',function() {
    ajaxFileUpload();
  });

  (...)

  function ajaxFileUpload() {
    jQuery.ajaxFileUpload ( {
        url:'../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/uploader.php', 
        secureuri:false,
        fileElementId:'uploadFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert('Error: ' + data.error + ' - Respons: ' + data.respons)
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
      }
    )
    return false;   
  }
```

To test that I data is submited, I have the following PHP code:

```
  $data['error']    = $_POST['current_path'];  // Gives me NULL
  $data['respons']  = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']; // Gives me NULL

  // Return result in json 
  echo json_encode($data);
```

**UPDATE**

After very good help from Pekka (with his good set of eyes), I have got it working! The code is updated with the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning

```
fileElementId:'uploadFile',
```

but your file field doesn't in fact have that ID.

And your PHP script should look in

```
$_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]
```

Comment: Well spotted! I added the ID but still get the same result :(

Comment: @STeven what does a `print_r($_POST)` yield?

Comment: @Steven also, more importantly, shouldn't it be `$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];`?

Comment: I can't see any output from PHP because it's all in an Iframe (I think). I've tested oouputting the content in a IFrame I hadded in HTML code, and all works fine. It only breaks when I try to use the Ajax plugin. I've also addded link to mye files if you want to download and have a look.

Comment: @Steven see my last comment, that's more important I think

Comment: Again well spottet. I've been looking at my code for so long that I have gotten "blind". Now everything works perfectly. Thanks you very much for your help. I've been stuck with this for three days and now I can finally move on. If I could award you more points, I would :)

Comment: Pekka, if u have time, could you take a look at a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699837/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-data

Comment: What makes ' vital instead of " ? I've always used them interchangably, aren't they just strings?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson it's not vital here (although take note that variables in strings wrapped in `'` won't be parsed)