# AjaxFileUpload Plugin does not retrieve $_POST data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload

This is almost identical problem which [I faced a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675908/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-or-files-data). I fixed it then, but now it's not working any more. Well, some of it works.

I'm using [AjaxFileUpload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) to upload files in my WP plugin. This plugin calls `uploader.php` to process the upload form.

I am able to get the filename (and other data) using `$_FILES['uploadFile']`, but I'm not able to retrieve `$_POST['current_path']` data.

I have a theory though. When I load the interface to upload data, the hidden input field 'current_path' is empty (as is hould be). As I navigate through my folders, the hidden input field is updated using jQuery.

When I hit the upload button, the Ajax File Upload plugin takes the data in the upload form and passes the data to `uploader.php` through `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.

But why am I able to get data from `$_FILES` and not from `$_POST`?

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
  //File upload functions
  // Remove feedback message on upload click 
    jQuery('.uploadImage').live('click',function() {
      ajaxFileUpload();
  });

  (...)

  //Lets upload the file by using Ajax uploader plugin
  function ajaxFileUpload() {
    alert(jQuery('input[type=hidden][name=current_path]').val()) //Shows me the correct current path   
    jQuery.ajaxFileUpload ( {
        url:'../wp-content/plugins/wp-filebrowser/uploader.php', 
        secureuri:false,
        fileElementId:'uploadFile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if(data.error != '') {
              alert(data.error);
          } else {
              alert(data.respons);
          } 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            jQuery('#uploadOutput').addClass('error').html('Error: ' + e).show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          // Update file list
        }
      }
    )
    return false;   
  }
```

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="current_path" name="current_path" value="<?php echo $fb->relative_url; ?>" />
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" class="button uploadImage" value="<?php _e('Upload File') ?>" /> <br />
</form>
```

PHP

```
$this->current_path   = $_POST['current_path'];
$this->data['error']  = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']; //Just for testing
$this->data['respons'] = "Filename: ".$_POST['current_path']; 

echo json_encode($this->data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why am I able to get data from $_FILES and not from $_POST?

Because you are not submitting the form, only the file input element.

It seems to be the plugin's behaviour [by design](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/):

> In this hacked version, it submits the specified file type of input element only rather than an entire form

The [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) can do both, maybe that helps.

Comment: shit. You're right. I've not been successfull using jQuery form plugin, but will give it another shot.