# AjaxFileUpload Plugin sometimes doesn't send POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm having intermittent problems, trying to  to upload files, using [ajaxfileupload.js](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/). Most times, the request has teh correct payload, as in A). But sometimes, the request gets sent off without the filename (and contents) as seen in [this pastebin (B)](http://pastebin.com/ubEbb9dV).

It seems to be similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699837/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-data). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675908/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-or-files-data) also talks about the problem. But I'm pretty sure I have the correctr element ID.

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699837/ajaxfileupload-plugin-does-not-retrieve-post-data) suggests using the jquery.form plugin ([here](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js) and [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)). But before I change components (having to re-engineer), I want to be sure there isn't an easy way to fix my current problem.

A)

```
    … 
    Request Payload
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXOoAbr8cm53B1pGS
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="convert"; filename="some-file.jpg"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    …
```

B)

http://pastebin.com/ubEbb9dV

Has someone had this problem before? Is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks

----> EDIT

So this is how I'm calling the function. i) The inputId passed in definitely exists. And ii) the file selected definitely exists on the file system. And this works most of the time. But now that I think about it, I'm using this plugin in conjunction with the "jquery.jeditable.js" plugin. Could that or any other plugin be turfing some functions in "ajaxfileupload"?

```
      $.ajaxFileUpload ( 
        {   
          url: '/api/upload/image',
          secureuri: false,
          fileElementId: inputId,
          success: successFn,
          error: errorFn
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery use GET as request Method. In the case of the question you reference here, Steven is not setting correctly the method property of for the ajax request. What I want to see i how you are sending the form (Your javascript/Jquery code).