# Get image name when uploading

Tags: php, ajax, uploading

I have form input as follows:

> -------------------------Form-------------------------
>
> Title : [text box]
>
> Category : [Combobox]
>
> Content : [Text area]
>
> Images : [File with multiple choose]
>
> [button]
>
> ------------------------End Form-----------------------

I am using PHP and AJAX when inserting data but have problems with uploading. I cannot get the file name (Image name) for uploading and inputting to the database.

Here is a little of my AJAX script:

```
data = "action=add&kode="+kode+"&file="+image+"&title="+title+"&categori="+categori+"&content="+content;
$.ajax({
    url: "action/prosesPOST.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg=="yes"){
        }else{
            $("#status").html("Failed...");
        }
        $("#status").html("");
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#form-box").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#table").load('action/prosesPOST.php?action=loaddata');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for the form? And the code where you're picking the value up from the form into your "image" variable? Or is the point of your question that you don't know how to do this bit?

Comment: ajax does not support file uploads. standard workaround is to have your JS create a hidden iframe and perform a standard post upload in there.

Comment: you could use some jQuery Ajax File Upload plugin for doing that

Comment: @Sepster I use : image = $("image").val();

Comment: @Marc Can u show me how to use Hidden iframe and getting name of file just for inserting to db ?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there, and they are all pretty decent.  Here are two: http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/ajax-a-simplified-version-of-file-upload-form-using-iframe/ and http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/ but to be honest, those were just the first two results from google... https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+file+upload+hidden+iframe Good luck!

Comment: `image = $("image").val();` isn't going to work... I presume you're using an `<input type='file'..>` input (which is why I wanted to see your HTML)?  Might be better to give that tag an `id='image-filename'` and then reference it by `image = $("#image-filename").val();`

Comment: @Sepster I was give id on <input type="file"..... and the id and name same is image,oh yah for $("image").val() it is wrong type sorry heheh i mean $("#image").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Ajax cant handle "uploading image" so i use hidden iframe method, like the comments the best way for me,

[Like this methode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that posts your files.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>

(function() {


    $('form').ajaxForm({

   complete: function(xhr) {
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
   }
    }); 

})();       
</script>`
```

Comment: I am using pure Jquery Ajax for inputing data,Uploading with iframe is best idea ! that will work like AJAX