# c# MVC3 ajax.beginform to upload file not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

After clicking the submit button. I am getting null in entity.
**Do anyone have a solution?**

View

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateRoom", "Room", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "window.location.href='Index'" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "ajaxUploadForm" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="Room" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    }
```

controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateRoom(RoomFileView entity)
    {
        //code
    }
```

model

```
     public class RoomFileView
    {
        public RoomFileView();

        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileWrapper Room { get; set; }

        public string Content();
    }
```

Comment: try as an Html.Form, and remove the OnComplete attr. If that works, then its a subtlely. If not, its something big we havent seen...

Comment: Try using `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm`

Answer (score 8):

I have written a little hack. It works fine in most of browsers, but FormData object doesn't supported in IE. You could add this code to you custom js file or html page.

```
window.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    var form = e.target;
    if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
        if (form.dataset.ajax) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                        var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                        if (updateTarget) {
                            updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(new FormData(form));
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Brilliant.  No idea what "but FormData object doesn't supported in IE" is trying to say but I needed this hack for Firefox to work as well as IE.  Haven't tested in Chrome yet.

Comment: Turns out this breaks Request.IsAjaxRequest() server side so it doesn't realise this is an Ajax request anymore.  Have you any idea how to fix that @Aleksey?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. Use the notmal Html.BeginForm. Please Check out this link [click here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) as this will be helpful for you.

If you want to use asynchronous uploads you may try some of the available upload components such as Ajax Upload and Uploadify.

Comment: Another solution (but no so simple one) is to convert your image to a base64 string and then decode it on the server.

Comment: I found this related response useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508202/6095334

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using AJAX.Beginform. 
There are many third party js controls available.
But i don't find them much useful. 
Either you have to use `<iframe>` or use Html.Beginform

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
var form = e.target;
if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
    if (form.dataset.ajax) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                    var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                    if (updateTarget) {
                        updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    } 
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(new FormData(form));
    }
}}, true);
```

Comment: Im using this script, but function defined in AjaxOptions for OnBegin and OnSuccess do not run...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use Ajax.BeginForm() to upload a file. I got around this by running an onclick() event on the submit event. I found this SO answer very useful: [Ajax.BeginForm is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082708/ajax-beginform-is-not-working-as-expected)