# Not able to upload file using Ajax.BeginForm() asynchronously

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to upload a file using Ajax.BeginForm(), but it's not working out.

My view contains:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST",     UpdateTargetId = "result" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <label id="lblUploadNewFile" for="fileUploadControl">Upload New File&lt;/label>
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileUploadControl"/>
   <input id="btnFileUpload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
   <span id="result" />
}
```

and the corresponding Controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadFile(FormCollection formData)
{
   HttpPostedFileBase file=null;

   try
   {
      file = Request.Files[0];
   }
   catch { }

   if ( file!=null &amp;&amp; file.ContentLength &gt; 0)
   {
      file.SaveAs(string.Concat(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)));

      return &quot;Successfully Uploaded&quot;;
   }
   else
   {
      return &quot;Upload Failed, please try again.&quot;;
   }
}
```

The problem is that it's uploading the file, but no longer doing any asynchronous posts when I remove `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. Instead, it does a full post-back.

When I add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in my view, it's doing it asynchronously, but it is not sending an upload file in the form data. No file is being sent to the server in `Request.Files[]`.

Comment: It's not possible with Ajax for obvious reasons: you could build a page hat uploads any accessible file on the visitors filesystem to the server without telling him.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. This is not supported. If you want to do that you could either use some file upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [Blueimp File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) or use the [`HTML 5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) if the client browser supports it.

Comment: thanks Darin for your reply, I'll try implementing Blueimp as Uploadify requires flash.

Comment: I'm using jQuery-asyncUpload shared by steven:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I don't understand your answer. As per [this other StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files), file uploading is actually supported and the way to do it is given in that other answer. Can you please clear what you say up?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Yes, could you please clarify us a little bit more regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this without additional libraries.

I came across this little hack, which resolves it nicely

```
window.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    var form = e.target;
    if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
        if (form.dataset.ajax) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                        var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                        if (updateTarget) {
                            updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(new FormData(form));
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Found http://www.acnenomor.com/1762557p1/c-mvc3-ajaxbeginform-to-upload-file-not-working

Comment: `http://www.acnenomor.com/1762557p1/c-mvc3-ajaxbeginform-to-upload-file-not-working` is no more; it was a scraper site copying Stack Overflow, you really found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972470/c-sharp-mvc3-ajax-beginform-to-upload-file-not-working).

Comment: whoever you are I'll find you and love you!

Comment: But how to implement the call back for the form ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get this work:
 get **jquery.form** library from nuget and import it to your cshtml file.You should create your form with **@Html.BeginForm**.
then bottom of your form write this script to ajax-ify your form:

```
$(function(){
  $('#formId').ajaxForm({
    complete:function(xhr){...},
    success:function(){...},
    error: function(){...}
  });
});
```

With these steps you can pass a file to controller.

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution:

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "post",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            OnBegin = "startLoader",
            OnSuccess = "Update_Record",
            UpdateTargetId = "Succ_Msg"
        },new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

notice the new `{ enctype = "multipart/form-data" }`
which tells the razor page to add the `enctype` that can pass `HttpPostedFileBase`

good luck:).

Comment: hey @tzuk, that's exactly what I've posted in question!

Comment: Does this technique require a particular version of .net framework? When I add `, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` to an existing Ajax.BeginForm that has AjaxOptions, then the action loses resolution. As if it's illegal. Using Rider, if it makes a difference, and .net framework v4.7.2.