# Ajax.BeginForm in MVC to upload files

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I was trying to use an example mentioned here [How to do a ASP.NET MVC Ajax form post with multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581703/how-to-do-a-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-post-with-multipart-form-data/13522052#13522052)

But I keep getting "fail" error message box

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<h2>Files Upload</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#form0").submit(function(event) {
        var dataString;
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $("#form0").attr("action");
        if ($("#form0").attr("enctype") == "multipart/form-data") {
            //this only works in some browsers.
            //purpose? to submit files over ajax. because screw iframes.
            //also, we need to call .get(0) on the jQuery element to turn it into a regular DOM element so that FormData can use it.
            dataString = new FormData($("#form0").get(0));
            contentType = false;
            processData = false;
        } else {
            // regular form, do your own thing if you need it
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json", //change to your own, else read my note above on enabling the JsonValueProviderFactory in MVC
            contentType: contentType,
            processData: processData,
            success: function(data) {
                //BTW, data is one of the worst names you can make for a variable

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //do your own thing
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }); //end .submit()
});
</script>
<div id="uploadDiv">
@Html.Action("Files", "Home")
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Files", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "uploadDiv", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id="form0"}))
{
<div>
    <div>Upload new file:
        <input type="file" name="file" /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
}
<br />
```

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult Files(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files;
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string saveLocation = @"D:\Files";
            string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(saveLocation, fileName);               


            try
            {
                file.SaveAs(fullFilePath);
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
                file.InputStream.Read(new byte[fileInfo.Length], 0, file.ContentLength);                    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TempData["FileUpload"] = e.Message;
                return PartialView();
            }
            files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Files\");
            return PartialView(files);
        }
        else
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Files\");
            return PartialView(files);
        }
    }
```

Files.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach (string f in Model)
{
<p>@f</p>
}
```

Global.asax

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this a while back - might help you out: http://blog.shadowmoses.co.uk/2013/06/handling-uploads-with-mvc4-jquery.html

Comment: You are missing route values on Ajax.BeginForm method.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

That is complicated better use [jquery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Here is the sample:

**Html.BeginForm**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="files"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}
```

**Action Method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void YourAction(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Verify that the user selected a file
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    // extract only the fielname
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    // TODO: need to define destination
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Progress Bar**

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery & Form script**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.progress-bar');
var percent = $('.progress-bar');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
```

**Update...**

People who are getting issue of calling action method twice is due to Ajax.BeginForm, just convert it to Html.BeginForm(). **For more clarification and to download sample code please refer at [this blog](http://www.dotnetpoints.com/file-upload-without-page-refresh-in-mvc-5)**.

Comment: try adding  dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
 in $('form').ajaxForm();

Comment: After adding this code in IE file uploder is disabled

Comment: @AshwiniVerma - With this I am not getting selected file in argument of the method - files,it is coming as null.Can you please tell me about this.Also I have not added Jquery and form script since I dont want progress bar.

Comment: @Saroj: You make sure file input's name attribute matches with action method's argument. In my example, it's *name="files"* <input type="file" name="files">.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma : I have checked those and it is fine ,still in argument the files shows null.Please help me..I need to solve this,its too urgent for me.If u want I can show you the code.I followed the exact steps mentioned by you even included the couple of links( src scripts) but not working.

Comment: I just want that file to be caught in the argument,rest I can take care of..Please help me

Comment: @AshwiniVerma : your sample work fine, but i don't understand why the action is called twice? first with null parameter and the second with non null parameter?

Comment: This is a void method.  After I submit, I want to return back to the form.

Comment: this is going to prevent updates. I cannot even change the view when adding this script

Comment: [this blog](http://mitracircle.com/post/5/file-upload-without-page-refresh-in-mvc) doesn't work. You can go instead to [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108516/File-Upload-Without-Page-Refresh-in-ASP-NET-MVC) or to the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20161109215400/http://mitracircle.com/post/5/file-upload-without-page-refresh-in-mvc).

Comment: @Saroj multipart/form-data is missing, use using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Answer (score 6):

The answer from `Ashwini Verma` is almost correct but it has a drawback, the form is submitted twice.

This is caused by the use of `Ajax.BeginForm()`. Using `Html.BeginForm()` will fix it.

Here's an example:

```
@* do not use Ajax.BeginForm() as it would cause the form to submit twice in connection with jQuery.Form *@
@using (var lForm = Html.BeginForm( 
  <ActionName>, <ControllerName>, FormMethod.Post, 
  new Dictionary<string, object> {{"name", <YourFormName>}, {"enctype", "multipart/form-data"}}))
{
```

Comment: You are right. It send the form twice, but how to work with Html.BeginForm() and put a UpdateTargetId?

Comment: @kavain Have a look at the HTML code generated by Ajax.BeginForm() and adopt it to the Html.BeginForm() call. It's basically all HTML tag attributes that will be parsed by the jQuery Ajax Unobtrusive plugin. So if you ensure that the attributes for the update target are generated correctly then target update should also work.

Answer (score 3):

You need html5 file handling and read file contents on client to get base64 encoded data.

On client you have to put:

```
<div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentFileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentFileSize)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentFileType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentFileContentsBase64)

    <input type="file" name="AttachmentFile" id="AttachmentFile" onchange="handleAttachmentFileChange(this.files)" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AttachmentFile)
</div>

<script>
    function handleAttachmentFileChange(files) {
        var file = files[0];
        $("#AttachmentFileName").val(file.name);
        $("#AttachmentFileSize").val(file.size);
        $("#AttachmentFileType").val(file.type || "application/octet-stream");

        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function () {
            fileReader.result;

            $("#AttachmentFileContentsBase64").val(fileReader.result);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
</script>
```

So your code will fill hidden fields with file data (filename, type, size, base64 encoded contents).
And on server side you put:

```
            if (AttachmentFileSize > 0)
            {
                string fileName = AttachmentFileName.Contains("\\") ? AttachmentFileName.Substring(AttachmentFileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) : AttachmentFileName;

                byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(AttachmentFileContentsBase64.Substring(AttachmentFileContentsBase64.IndexOf(',') + 1));

//save file to file system or db

                ModelState.Remove("CurrentAttachmentFileId");
                ModelState.Remove("CurrentAttachmentFileName");

            }
            else if (AttachmentFileSize == -1)
            {
//remove existing file from fs or db
            }
```

The code needs to be modified with your models and logic but it worked for me