# upload file with other parameters through ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am working in asp.net mvc using c#.

I want to upload an image which is selected from file browser window and is included inside a form tag.

```
<form id="uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput"/>
```

In the same view,I have other fields which is not a part of the form.I am sending those fields through ajax by converting them to JSON Object..Along with this i want to add the image also...Please help me to do this...

Comment: show your json code..!

Comment: Show me your json passing parameter

Comment: use this example which I posted couple of months ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files/19044689#19044689

Answer (score 1):

As question not much clear I'm showing example here what I assumed.

you can use [jquery forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

**Add jquery forms plugin**

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

**ViewPage**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //I assume other fields are 
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"/>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"/> 
    //Image upload
    <input type="file" name="files"> 
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public void YourAction(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string FirstName, string LastName)
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    // Verify that the user selected a file
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        // extract only the fielname
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        // TODO: need to define destination
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a file via AJAX, you can use HTML5 FileReader API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

The API allows you to read the contents of the files (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

### FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()

Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's data.

### FileReader.readAsBinaryString()

Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file as a string.

### FileReader.readAsDataURL()

Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains a data: URL representing the file's data.

### FileReader.readAsText()

Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains the contents of the file as a text string.

You can then send the contents of the file as Base64 encoded string with all other data that you have.

Note that this works only in IE10+ and other modern browsers.