# How would I rewrite this as an ajax form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble with turning this code into an `Ajax form`. How would I go about doing so?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "CollaborativeProjects", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
     <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Comment: Check these SO answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery.form plugin

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

if you don't want to add any plugins, you have to add submit event and write native ajax code.