# Submit Button Calls RenderAction instead of Posting a Form Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently finding problem with my submit button.

I have a page (say **Page A**) and within this **"Page A"**, I called a **PartialView** using the **RenderAction("ActionName", "Controller", "Parameters")**.

The **PartialView** displays correctly. There is a **BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})** and a **Submit** button in this "Page A" and when I click on the button, the formpost method called the **RenderAction()** instead of the **FormPost** method.

Please help me solve this challenge since my search for solution on this forum and elsewhere is not yielding any results.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Ajax.BeginForm()

If you are using "multipart/form-data" that is mean you are uploading a file with your form.

You can check this out.

[Ajax.BeginForm in MVC to upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response brother. I am not trying to upload a file. What is happening is that when I comment on the RenderAction, I am able to post the form content to the controller even with the same form without change.