# ASP Mvc Ajax.BeginForm doesn't post File and Html.BeginForm breaks the design?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxform

I've trying to send a file through Ajax.beginForm with enctype = "multipart/form-data", but I always get it as null,

I'm returning a JavaScriptResult from My controller like this,

```
public JavaScriptResult SaveFile(MyModel model)
{
    JavaScriptResult result = new JavaScriptResult();
    result.Script = "$('#ShowPopup').trigger('click')";

    return result;
}
```

When using Html.BeginForm it works great, but when it returns the result, it shows the following on the browser,

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with Html.BeginForm(), also when I'm returning a view, the view returns but without the my _Layout.cshtml page, breaks my design,

so the problem is when I use ajax it perfectly great but doesn't post file, 
and when I'm using html.beginForm, it posts the file, but breaks the design after return.

Comment: you want to upload a file through ajax?

Comment: What properties does your `MyModel` contains??

Comment: If you want to post using ajax, you need to use `FormData` as shown in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681). And then you can just call `"$('#ShowPopup').trigger('click')";` in the success callback rather than trying to return a script.

Comment: You can use an Html.BeginForm and in java script convert it to ajax request in javascript using [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). I use it and it works great. Please look at the questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037948/not-able-to-upload-file-using-ajax-beginform-asynchronously) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files)