# How to upload file using ajax.beginform in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, asyncfileupload

My view:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "CustomerEngagement", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "closePopUpAndShowNextPost", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "post" }, new { @id = "create" }))
{
    // Lots of things going on here 
    // I need to implement fileupload to upload attachments asynchronously here 
    <input name="fileupload1" id="fileupload1" multiple type="file" />
    <button id="fileupload" name = "upload">
    //Button to submit the form
    <button id="save" value="save">
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string word, StudentModel model)
{
    List<string> synonyms = new List<string>();
    List<string> sugg = new List<string>();
    //Doing lot of stuff here
    // I'm trying to get httppostedfilebase here but its null, also request.Files[] coming null. 
}
```

I think in `ajax.beginform` file is not uploaded, can we have any other solution here?

Comment: Include the `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` html attribute

Comment: tried doesn't work with that as well

Comment: You cannot upload a file using AJAX - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037948/not-able-to-upload-file-using-ajax-beginform-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot upload using AJAX as it is not supported, you can however use some plugins such as Ajax Upload and Uploadify. Many of which are found here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-ajax-file-uploader-plugins/

You can also follow this tutorial:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

Using this we can get the file in ajax.begin form

```
$("body").on("submit", "#frmAddEditProcess", function (e) {
    var form = e.target;
    if (form.dataset.ajax) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                    var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                    if (updateTarget) {
                        updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        OnEmployeeCertificationSuccess();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        if ($("#frmAddEditProcess").valid()) { xhr.send(new FormData(form)); }
    } return true;
});
```