# using Ajax.js and JQuery.js post multiple file as null

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, null

I want to use Ajax.BeginForm which contains a `input type="file"` multiple. But file value is null if i send it to controller. Because using together JQuery.js and Ajax.js. If I delete Jquery in this View file value not null.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Send", "Home",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="result",HttpMethod="POST",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace},new {enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input name="name"  />

    <input   id="files" name="pictures" type="file" multiple />
    <button type="submit"  >SEND</button>

}

<div id="result"></div>
```

//Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Send(string name,IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> pictures)
    {

        //int sayi = resimler.Count();
        ViewBag.a = "abcsados";

        return PartialView("veriler",ViewBag.a);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow,  please don't share code images because its not helpful, add code here directly. avoid external links, or just create a snippet and add link to it here

Comment: Okey! I edited it

Comment: is this in asp.net? right

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. This is not supported. If you want to do that you could either use some file upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [Blueimp File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) or use the [`HTML 5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) if the client browser supports it.

[Answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037987/2996989)