# MVC4 Ajax jQuery 2

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone know what I need to get the `ajax.beginform` to work in my MVC4 project?  I updated the jQuery library to version 2 and I have included the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` but the form is still posting to the new page rather than just updating the `UpdateTargetId` element

I have had a google and a lot of people seem to be having problems with a script called `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` but this isn't in my project.  Do I need to install this, and if so do I then need to do a find and replace on `live` so that it uses `on` instead?

This is the form code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddImage", "Quote", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Files" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
}
```

This posts to the quote controller addimage action and all that does is write out a string to the screen (which should appear in the `Files` div) but instead of doing an ajax call it is actually going to the Quote/AddImage page

Comment: Code! You need to post your code for us to help you!

Comment: @KingJulian There isn't much code for this, have posted my form code.  The question is more about what js libraries do I need to include to get ajax.beginform to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do in the end was download the latest `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` through nuget.  This has been updated so it works with jquery 2

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing InsertionMode in your AjaxOptions.

Second, it seems you're trying to upload files using Ajax form? You won't be able to. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972470/c-sharp-mvc3-ajax-beginform-to-upload-file-not-working), for example.

Finally, Ajax.BeginForm is using jQuery.live() function, which has been [removed as of jQuery version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095870/mvc4-ajax-beginform-not-replacing-updatetargetid) for more info.

You should install [jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/download/) which will restore deprecated features. This will at least restore your Ajax form functionality. Alas, it won't help you upload files through Ajax. But that's a different topic.

Comment: +1 for the file upload bit, but the latest version of the unobtrusive ajax works with jquery 1.9 and higher