# Ajax.BeginForm is not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

I have a very strange problem with Aajx.BeginForm. I have this code :

In view :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "Profile", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="file" name="files"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    }
```

In controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // TODO: need to define destination
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get null file when the form is submit. I read many question that is the same of my question, but most of the answers was that the name of input type="file" is not as the same name of the parameter name in the controller. I found some examples, I try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files/19044689#19044689) which is almost the same of my code except for the jquery files, so I tried to replace the jquery files with these files :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

And here is the surprise !!. When the form is submit, I get the file but the form is post back. It is work as there is no ajax. I search in google for Ajax.BeginFrom that is post back and found many solutions in stackoverflow and most of of the answers was that **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax** file must be included in the page. It like a circle of problems, once you solve one you get another. Does I miss something ?

Comment: You cannot submit a file with `Ajax.BeginForm`. You can use `FormData` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: I use FormData, but still not work. It is return null. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then show the code you tried - I can't guess what mistakes you have made :). But in any case you only have a single file input but specify the parameter as `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. Use either `multiple` in the file input or change the parameter to just `HttpPostedFileBase`

Comment: I change the parameter to HttpPostedFileBase, but still not work. What code you need ? This is all the code.

Comment: You said your tried the code in the link I gave you in my first comment (which does work - assuming your using a modern browser). If its not working for you, post the code you tried

Comment: I update the question when the first answer say that I should use FormData. I add new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }to Ajax.BeginFrom and still not work. Please review the question again.

Comment: No, you need to read the answer in the ink I gave you - you need to use `FormData` which is NOT the same thing as `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`!

Comment: Sorry for that, but you say I can't submit a file with ajax.beginform. There are many tutorials on youtube and on stackoverflow that show how to do that. Why your saying that ?

Comment: Because its a fact! (ajax does not allow multipart/form-data enctype)

Comment: I will agree with you because I can't find any way to make ajax.BeginForm work. I suggest that you post an answer that show why ajax.BeginForm can't work and explain an alternative method to do ajax file upload. This will help other people who will see this question.

Comment: The link I gave you showed how to do this :) But I will add an answer later explaining why `Ajax.BeginForm()` cannot be used for submitting files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit files with `Ajax.BeginForm()`. The helper uses the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file to submit the data using ajax functions which do not allow `multipart/form-data enctype`.

One option is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) (but not supported in older browsers). Change the `Ajax.BeginForm()` to `Html.BeginForm()` and then handle the forms submit event

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function() {
      .... // do something?
    }       
  });
});
```

In addition there are numerous jquery plugins that you can use for uploading files (14 of them are listed [here](http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/))

Side note: Your file input allows selection of only one file, so your method parameter should be `HttpPostedFileBase files` (not `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files`) or alternatively, include the `multiple` attribute in the file input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the encoding type in your form.

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="file" name="files"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same problem. The form return null file.