# Sending file data with ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have got issue sending file to a server with ajax for submitting. I tried lots of methods with  `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` and `$.ajax({});` but always its gives error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I also use `processData: false`, but in this condition I got all form fields apart file field.

My Code for ajax is:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( 'file', $('#file')[0].files[0] );
fd.append( 'name', 'test');
$.ajax({
    url: "uploadFile.php",
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    // processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

In this I got only `name` field with value `test` in output, but not `file`.
Somebody please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: form code required and did you add jquery library or not?

Comment: Maybe `fd.value` in your data

Comment: I added jquery library in my html
and my html is `<form method="post" action="" id="send" action="uploadFile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="Submit"/>
</form><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Have strings as your data values.Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324594/jquery-illegal-invocation and let me know if you have any problems

Comment: Can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459429/sending-a-formdata-object-to-server-with-ajax-contains-files

Answer (score 0):

Set contentType to specific format instead of false.
For eg. in case of image set it to :- "image/jpeg" etc.