# File Upload without using the file upload control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am uploading a file in my application using a html file upload control now. Instead of file upload control,on selecting checkbox controls I need to  fetch the file from local disk.I am using Javascript code in my application.Can Anyone help me out in this.

Comment: Use a hidden file upload control , and onclick of checkbox , trigger the file upload click

Comment: Can you share some code? Is the fie <input> already populated when you click the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FormData javascript object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects but just modern browsers will have that one. For older browsers you can use a iframe [How to make Asynchronous(AJAX) File Upload using iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden file upload control and manipulate it using JavaScript. I use the code below to allow the user to select a profile image and see it in place before uploading. I use a link, but you can change it to a checkbox like you requested:

```js
function LoadImage() {
  document.getElementById("ImageFile").click();
}

function DisplayImage(FileBrowser) {
  if (FileBrowser.files.length < 1)
    return;
  var file = FileBrowser.files[0].name;
  if (file == null || file == "")
    return;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("ImageDisplay").src = this.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(FileBrowser.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input id="ImageFile" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; height : 0; width: 0;" onchange="DisplayImage(this);" />
<a href="javascript: void LoadImage();">
  <img id="ImageDisplay" alt="Select an image" src="" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.I just want to avoid the manual selection of the file.Instead I want to select the file as a back end process.Is this possible.The file path and file name will be static.

Comment: Selecting a file MUST be a manual process because web browsers don't have access to the file system for security and privacy reasons. The only way to do it in a web browser is to include a binary executable such as a Java Applet which can access the file system, but it has to be trusted by the user.