# File Upload control and Ajax AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Can any one tell me what is the difference between both of them and also why File Upload control doesn't work with Update Panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported by web browsers.

[Why don't file uploads work during async postbacks?](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/03/30/why-don-t-file-uploads-work-during-async-postbacks.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743/fileupload-control-inside-an-updatepanel-without-refreshing-the-whole-page) [thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1105208/1689084.aspx).