# how to upload an image file without any postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading a file using the `<asp:FileUpload>` and `<asp:button>` controls but I want to do it without a postback. On button click I execute the following code.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);  //fileupload1 is the <asp:fileupload ID
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + strFileName + ""));
    imgUpload.ImageUrl = "../UploadFile/" + strFileName + "";  //imgupload is the <img ID on which I am showing the image after upload
    imgUpload.Visible = true;
}
```

After uploading the file I am showing the saved image from the specified folder in my project solution, but on clicking the upload button the whole page gets loaded and I don't want the postback on clicking the upload button.

Comment: You mean you want an AJAX upload or the page reload is causing you an issue by resetting fields etc?

Comment: Try this stackoverflow link : 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743/fileupload-control-inside-an-updatepanel-without-refreshing-the-whole-page


Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
just add the script

    <script language="javascript">
        function Change(obj) {
             __doPostBack("<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>", "");
        }

      </script>


Call the script in your button click event like this 
<pre>
onchange="Change(this);"
</pre>   

Your image control added in the update panel with contentTemplate 

    <asp:FileUpload ID="imgFileUploader" runat="server"   />
             <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server"  
         Text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click" onchange="Change(this);" />
      <br />
        <br />
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
  &nbsp;<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>    
               <img id="imgOrginal" runat="server" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" />
              </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[for more details](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/558327/Show-uploaded-image-without-postback)

Comment: Thanks for the solution....but it's been a little too late for the implementation...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about uploading files through partial request. Using ASP.NET file upload control it is not possible. Even it is wrapped inside update panel, it will not work. It needs to have synchronous trigger to make it work, that means it does full post back.

If you are using ASP.NET AJAX, checkout asyncfileload control and newly added 'Ajax file upload' control. These controls are present in Ajax control tool kit. Please go through the documentation since each have their limitations.

If they doesn't suit your needs, try for open source Ajax file upload controls like neat upload etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ASP.Net file uploader then is is not possible.. you can use Ajax file uploader for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Best way to upload images without any postback, you can try AsyncFileUpload control in Asp.net Ajax. A good example is here :-

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASP.Net-AJAX-Control-Toolkits-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using simple ASP.NET WebForms.

Do some research into what is known as the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Code behind methods like the one you've included are / can be executed only as part of a postback or server-side action.

If you want client-server interaction *without* a postback then you need to use javascript. You can use javascript alongside ASP.NET, and I believe there is a Microsoft implementation of 'AJAX' in the .NET framework.

Comment: Yes there are Ajax implementations like [Ajax.AjaxMethod]. But the problem there I am facing is I am not able to save the file in the specified directory. If you can please elaborate on the Microsoft implementation of 'AJAX'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax for this purpose. There are plenty of examples available on internet. Just google it.

Comment: yenda unakku intha vela