# read local JPG file within browser

Tags: jquery, .net

I am really struggling with this one: forgive me if the answer is right in front of my face.

I'm trying to find the easiest way to upload a JPG file through ajax.  I only need the byte array, which I can handle later: the challenge, I need to be able to do this all (or mostly) in javascript: most solutions I've looked at use a php script, which I cannot use.  I really just need a byte stream that I can handle afterwards.

I've looked at solutions such as [this](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.ca/2008/04/how-to-raise-events-for-fileupload.html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049905/how-to-upload-an-image-file-without-any-postback-in-asp-net), neither of which have resulted in much success.  I really don't need it to do much: I just need the byte array, and a postback cannot occur: if I need to grab the byte array on my final submission (after the image has been chosen) that would also work: I just don't know how to go about pulling information from an asp:FileUpload element from the client side if the file hasn't been uploaded.

Thanks all.

Comment: You could get the file data using javascript if you're in a modern browser, though i'm not sure *what* data you can get, i haven't messed around with that api yet due to needing to support browsers that don't support the api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: Stop calling it an upload if you don't want to do a postback. without a postback, it's not an upload. That might be why you're having problems finding search results. also, if you're not doing a postback, there's absolutely nothing .net or php can do for you. All you have access to are things that can run on the client such as javascript, css, html, html5 apis, canvas, svg, flash, etc.

Comment: I ran across something called [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) that may allow me to read the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do this using an asp:FileUpload object, and no postback via. use of javascript's [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).  With FileReader, as long as the end user chooses a file, file information (such as bytes) are available to javascript, and can be read.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do any kind of server manipulation without server side scripting, such as PHP, ASP, java etc. If that was the case, it would be major security issue, since anyone can upload anything onto the host(server).

As far as certain data that you want to grab, you can use Actionscript 3 to pull image data (but it would require user to have Adobe Flash installed)

Comment: I understand that.  I am using ASP .NET.  I've struggled in finding a simple ASP .NET solution, is really what it boils down to.

Comment: That is fine - it is just a timing concern, and the form submit is mainly handled in javascript: I just need to pull that information from the server side (somehow), I guess.