# stop jquery ui window from closing after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, state

I have a jquery UI window that has a set of text boxes and an image uploader. ive got it up and running great, but am having an issue with the image uploader.

When the user clicks to upload their image, the code fires ok, but returns after postback to the same page, but displayed as a flat page (i.e. no UI window and no styling).

IM guessing that as the page has postback it knows nothing about its previous state. Apologies for the noob sort of question, I would normally be on MVC projects and could do this in my sleep lol.

Can anyone offer any advice on what I may do. code:

This loads the window from a grid:

```
$("a[name^='editSection_']").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var divDiag = $("#addEdit");


    $.ajax({
        url: "/edit.aspx?id=" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            $(divDiag).html(data);
            $(divDiag).dialog({
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                title: "Editing Feature Box",
                height: 800,
                width: 740,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                option: "show",
                close: function (ev, ui) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(divDiag).html(data);
            $(divDiag).dialog({

                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                title: "Editing Feature Box",
                height: 800,
                width: 740,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                option: "show",
                close: function (ev, ui) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the HTML for the image uploader..

```
        <asp:FileUpload ID="editImage" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadImage" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadImage_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code runs on the btnUploadImage:

```
    protected void btnUploadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (editImage.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
    .....code to upload sits here
```

Once the upload has executed I want to drop straight back to the UI window with the same state as before..

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the File Upload control does a full postback on the page in order to upload the file so the opened dialog is lost. From what I see you have two options:

- Reopen the Jquery dialog after the postback in the same state that it was before (in your case this may not be possible or desirable)
- Change the File Upload control to something else. Maybe an ajax upload would be a better choice here, like [this one](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx).

Comment: I would have loved to use ajax. Can I use something like I would have in MVC. i.e. catch button click, e.preventdefault then called a controller action to do the server bits?

Comment: @bruceiow preventdefault would've normally work, but the file upload requires a postback in order to upload the file. There are lots of other options, I updated the answer with me recommendation, see [other threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743/fileupload-control-inside-an-updatepanel-without-refreshing-the-whole-page) for more

Answer (score 0):

if you are good in jquery then  use the following jquery components 
you will have to customize this for your solution

[Dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)